# How to sort by multiple properties in Spring Data (JPA) derived queries?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking at the examples giving on this page (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories) about method naming, is it possible to create a complex chain method name such as

```
findByProgrammeAndDirectorAndProgDateBetweenOrderByProgDateStartTimeAsc
```

In the example they give, they are only doing an OrderBy on one value. In the example above `ProgDate` and `StartTime` would be two separate values.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

The trick is to simply delimit the properties you want to sort by using the direction keywords `Asc` and `Desc`. So what you probably want in your query method is something like:

```
…OrderByProgDateAscStartTimeAsc
```

Note, how we conclude the first property definition by `Asc` and keep going with the next property.

Generally speaking, we recommend switching to `@Query` based queries, once method names exceed a certain length or complexity. The main reason being that it's awkward for clients to call these very long methods. With `@Query` you rather get the full power of the query language plus a reasonably sized method name that might be of higher level language to express the intent of the query.

Comment: is there any way to order by `JoinColumn` id?

Thanks

Comment: @Laxman check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084064/spring-jpa-pagerequest-ordering-by-a-join-column

Comment: It doesn't work if there are no any conditions. So findByIdOrderByStartAscIdDesc works, but findAllOrderByStartAscIdDesc doesn't.

Comment: Is it possible to combine `OrderBy` method keyword with `Sort` parameter in a `Pageable` object?

Answer (score 13):

I am Sharing one other approach code snippet for implementing get operation where performing sort operation ordered by multiple column

```
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        Order StartTimeOrder = new Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "StartTime");
        orders.add(StartTimeOrder);
        Order progDateOrder = new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "ProgDate");
        orders.add(progDateOrder);
        return repository.findAll(Sort.by(orders));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: What import is for Order?

Comment: org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
    org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order;

Comment: @abhinavkumar Can I use this for a date range ie  Order StartTimeOrder = new Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "StartTime"-"endTime");

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's should be possible:

Try this:

```
findByProgrammeAndDirectorAndProgDateBetweenOrderByProgDateStartTimeAsc(String programme, String director, Date progStart, Date progEnd);
```

I have not tested the code, but according to things I've already done, it should work.

Comment: Is that signature correct? I would think the Between covers the progStart and progEnd, but OrderByProgDateStartTimeAsc, would that need an additional two parameters?

Comment: @PaulStatham I believe it's right. Between needs two Dates and the Order don't need any argument, since you are instructing to order by a value that is matched by the column, like in SQL ... ORDER BY ProgDateStartTime ASC

Answer (score 2):

A bit more compact :

```
return repository.findAll(
  Sort.by(List.of(
    new Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "StartTime"),
    new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "ProgDate")
  ))
);
```

or

```
return repository.findAll(
  Sort
  .by(Direction.DESC, "StartTime")
    .and(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "ProgDate"))
);
```

Comment: can we use this for the date range like return repository.findAll(
  Sort
  .by(Direction.DESC, "StartTime"-"EndTime")