# Spring JPA PageRequest ordering by a join column

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using the Spring PageRequest to sort (order) a custom query by a column in my database.

If I'm doing a custom query such as :

```
 @Query( value = "select h from hunterhouse h join h.queens q where q.name = 'Computer Science'")
```

Is it not possible to sort by a column in q, the table I am joining to?

```
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC, "q.region");
```

debug comes out as "order by h.q.region" which is incorrect, is it not possible to order by a join column?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You simply put the complete path you want to join on into the sort expression. So what you'd need to use is `queens.region` which will then be translated into `h.queens.region` and appended to the JPQL query you defined.

Comment: I can only get this working for a one to one join. Hunterhouse - Queens is a one to many join. Whenever I input "queens.region" , hibernate doesn't even insert this into the query "order by . desc".

Comment: I understand this approach but my problem is that the sorting data is coming from Swagger... So the person putting in the field name doesn't know that is comes from a specific table and the sorting is not working. If the complete name of the field (including the table) is used then the sorting works perfecly. I cannot find anything on the topic, I don't even know what to search...
Can you maybe suggest a pointer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem! This bug was fixed in Spring Data JPA 1.7.3 - just make sure you have a version higher or equal to 1.7.3! After that it will work with `queens.region`

Spring source: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-726