# Sort by joined table's field Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity classes Request,User:

```
//Ommiting some annotations for brevity
 public class User{    
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private Integer age;
}

public class Request{
  private Long id;
  private String message;
  private Date createTime;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
  private User user;
}
```

I can sort request list by create time :

```
Sort = new Sort(Direction.ASC,"createTime");
```

Is there a possible way to sort request list by User's name? Like:

```
Sort = new Sort(Direction.ASC,"User.name");
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084064/spring-jpa-pagerequest-ordering-by-a-join-column

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. `new Sort(Direction.ASC,"user.name");` should work just fine.

Spring Data JPA will left outer join the User to the Request and order by the joined column's name resulting in SQL like this:

```
select 
  id, message, createTime 
from 
  Request r 
  left outer join User u on u.id = r.user_id 
order by 
  u.name asc
```

This works great on one-to-one and, like you have here, many-to-one relationships but because a left outer join is employed to implement the order by clause, if the joined entity represents a many relationship (like in a one-to-many), the `Sort` may result in SQL in which duplicate records are returned.  This is the case because the `Sort` parameter will always result in a new left outer join even if the entity being joined is already joined in the query!

**Edit** Incidentally, there is an open ticket concerning this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-776

Comment: This works perfectly but I cannot understand how to make it work if the parameter is decided by a user from swagger... The user will input name and not u.name and then it doesn't work. In case the user uses u.name all works as expected :(