# How to handle SQL_Injection and Second_Order_SQL_Injection vulnerabilities scanned by checkmarx?

Tags: java, spring, security, sql-injection, checkmarx

The SQL_Injection and Second_Order_SQL_Injection vulnerability appears in the source code of the project using the spring data jpa framework, scanned with **checkmarx**

What do I do with them? do you have any suggestions, thanks

1. An injection vulnerability has been detected in "password"

```
public interface AccRepository extends BaseRepository<Acc, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM acc WHERE username = ?1 and password = ?2",nativeQuery = true)
    Acc selectAcc(String username, String password);
}
```

Comment: This code is already protected. Either that "checkmarx" thingy gave you false positives or there is another code which is vulnerable. The latter must be rewritten the same way as this code is written, using parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid SQL Injection in Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997976/avoid-sql-injection-in-spring-jpa)