# Getting Second Order SQL Injection in Spring Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, security, sql-injection, checkmarx

I am facing *Second Order SQL Injection* in the Spring-Hibernate application after scanning through the *Checkmarx* tool, I have gone through multiple questions in StackOverflow and in other platforms as well but did not get the right finding.

could you please look into the below code snip,

```java
public String getOrderId(order_name){
    String returnId= null;
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select order_id from order where order_name=?");
    List<String> dataset = query.setParameter(1,order_name).getResultList();
    if(dataset!=null){
       returnId = dataset. Get(0);
    }
 return returnId;
}
```

In this above method, while calling `getResultList()`, getting a high vulnerability issue that, this method returns data flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and eventually used in further database query in the method.

Earlier code was like this,

```java
public String getOrderId(order_name){
   String returnId= null;
   String q = "select order_id from order where    order_name="+order_name;
   Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(q);
```

and directly it was used as a string append in query, which I have modified with set parameter,

```java
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select order_id from order where order_name=?");
List<String> dataset = query.setParameter(1,order_name).getResultList();
```

but still after getting data from `query.getResultSet()`, it is asking for sanitizing and validating the data before use in further database query method.

and this return data is being used in further query like `select * from return_Data where clause`. (properly used in where clause to set parameter to avoid SQL injection).

and in the above query is used in another method where we pass return_Data as input to it.

could you please help here to know what checks and validation can be added to overcome this type of issue. Thanks in advance for prompt response.

Comment: Please format you question with code elements and so

Comment: Please add the Checkmarx comment you get from the system

Comment: There is absolutely nothing special in the "second order sql injection", it's SQL injection all the same. you just prevent it exactly the same way as other

Comment: Is there any thing apart from this to prevent it :- Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select order_id from order where order_name=?");
List<String> dataSet = query.setParameter(1,order_name).getResultList(); as after preventing still checkmarx showing the same for sanity and validate the data which return from getResultList() method.

Comment: whatever returned from getResultList() method, is not related to SQL, let alone injections. N'est-ce pas?

Comment: Whatever returned from getResultList() method, that is being used in another method as a query parameter input in the query, where it is linked.

Comment: again. whatever **returned** from getResultList() method, is not related to SQL. Period. It doesn't make it linked to another method. At all. Another method is another method. Whatever data used in some other method, being it returned from getResultList or any other source, is a subject of the regular protection. There is no link.

Comment: this returned value is being used there as a table name in another method's query, like:- Select * from tableName,  and this tableName is the returnedValue which we append in the query.

Comment: first of all, your database structure is WRONG, in capital letters, if you need to use a dynamical table name, let alone taken as a data from SQL. Yet again, what happens in another method, happens in another method. It doesn't matter whether it was returned by getResultList or anything. You must protect SQL in this another method not because the data is coming from getResultList. But because you must protect SQL.

Comment: And when I scann through the checkMarx tool, it shows the comment with high errors vul, that- the data which we get from the getResultList() is not sanitized and validated properly which is being used further in the another method's query. hope you are getting the problem,

Comment: Let me ask you in different way, this database structured is being used in huge way, as it quite old hence would be tough to modify, but lets say, if we are getting tableName dynamically from the Users, in that case how can we use in the nataiveQuery to avoid the SQL injection ? currenlty it is used like :- (select * from"+table_name+) then we trigger this, this the sql injection, please consider this scanario.

Comment: Finally I found the solution before using the data into the query, just sanitized this with removing the possible special characters then used that string in the query. Thank you  
- baruchiro for the coordination & Help to understand this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid SQL Injection in Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997976/avoid-sql-injection-in-spring-jpa)

Comment: Yes, some short of for the same scenario, in my case, I am getting the table name from the user input and for that I have to do sanitization and validation before using in sql query. But this article helped me to get more confident on this, Thank you, It was nice and knowledgeable discussion with you....