# How to sort by multiple properties and then Order By in Spring Data (JPA)

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data JPA and i´m trying to create a query to sort results by 2 names and then order by the First name. 
Is it possible to do all that with only one query on spring data?

```
List<something> findByNameOrderByNameDesc(Collection<String> listNames);  // I want to use some thing like this
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us a minimal example of the work you have done so far. Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: possible duplicated of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380984/how-to-sort-by-multiple-properties-in-spring-data-jpa-derived-queries