# JPA doesn't sort records by LocalDate and LocalTime

Tags: java, mysql, spring, datetime, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with sorting records from my database.
There are 10 matches that have `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` variables and they are not being sorted by (at first) `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`. This is what I get from database:

```
2020-04-04 13:00:00
2020-04-04 15:00:00
2020-04-04 16:00:00
2020-04-04 19:00:00
2020-04-04 20:00:00
2020-04-04 16:00:00
2020-04-04 22:00:00
2020-04-04 18:00:00
2020-04-04 23:00:00
2020-04-04 23:30:00
```

but should be:

```
2020-04-04 13:00:00
2020-04-04 15:00:00
2020-04-04 16:00:00
2020-04-04 16:00:00
2020-04-04 18:00:00
2020-04-04 19:00:00
2020-04-04 20:00:00
2020-04-04 22:00:00
2020-04-04 23:00:00
2020-04-04 23:30:00
```

My match entity (class is called `Game` due to mysql problems):

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Team teamBlue;

    @OneToOne
    private Team teamRed;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate localDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
    private LocalTime localTime;

}
```

JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT g FROM Game g ORDER BY g.localDate, g.localTime ASC")
    List<Game> findUpcomingMatches();
}
```

Also I don't think this is how columns should look like for `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` variables.

[image]

At first I thought there might be a problem with my SQL Query, but after some research I came to the conclusion that it might be ok.
If anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: How does the generate SQL for the query look like?

Comment: What are the generated datatypes of the columns?

Comment: SQL Query (in JpaRepository): `@Query("SELECT g FROM Game g ORDER BY g.localDate, g.localTime ASC")`

Comment: datatypes for columns:
`local_date`: DATETIME(6),
`local_time`: DATETIME(6)

Comment: No the generate query form Hibernate. You can set in application.properties logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug and then you will see it

Comment: Why you won't use jpa method naming feature ? Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380984/how-to-sort-by-multiple-properties-in-spring-data-jpa-derived-queries

Comment: @SimonMartinelli https://pastebin.com/4XHGiWXH. There are also other variables that I didn't mention to make this topic clearer.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I tried `List<Game> findAllByOrderByLocalDateAscLocalTimeAsc();`, didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to store a single timestamp in two columns. Most database designers use just one `@LocalDateTime` (`TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` in MySQL) column for that purpose, because the datatype has room for both date and time, and, well, they `ORDER` correctly.

Your example table contents make it look like the date part of your `localTime` column is set to the date on which the row was inserted.  So that bogus date makes your ordering wrong.

If you have a good reason not to change your data model to use just one column, try this query.

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Game g ORDER BY DATE(g.localDate) ASC, TIME(g.localTime) ASC")
List<Game> findUpcomingMatches();
```

It keys off just the date in your first column and just the time in your second column.

But change your data model if you possibly can.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I will consider changing `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` into `LocalDateTime`. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Game g ORDER BY g.localDate ASC, g.localTime ASC")
List<Game> findUpcomingMatches();
```

Try this,

Comment: I also tried this, and it did not work. Sorry, I forgot to mention that